# Sql server stored procedure installation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I own a small part of an application. I have many stored procs ~50-100 of them to be installed in each environment. I am preparing script for installling them.

Whats the best way to install about 50-100 stored procs in the sql server 2012. I am only wanting to install and point it to a .sql file. That file will contain the script and does the If Not EXISTS CHECK, drops and recreates it. But then I will need to run all of them manually. I want to be able to trigger the .sql scripts via some type of scripting or batch file.

Can someone please give some pointers...Thanks.

Comment: Check out [`sqlcmd.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773(v=sql.110).aspx).

Comment: check out SQL Server data tools in visual studio.  Build a dacpac of the base database then build a project with just your procs in it.  You can do a publish that will check against the database for any delta's that need to be deployed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sqlcmd.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773(v=sql.110).aspx):

```
sqlcmd -S server\instance -U username -P password -i C:\script.sql -o C:\results.txt
```

Put all 50-100 check/drop/create commands in a single file and then create a batch file containing the above.